# Django: How to hide Traceback in unit tests for readability?

Tags: django, unit-testing

I find it a bit irritating getting so much details for a simple failed unit test. Is it possible to suppress everything but the actual defined assert message?

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_get_sales_item_for_company (my_app.tests.SalesItemModelTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kave/projects/my/my_app/tests.py", line 61, in test_get_sales_item_for_company
    self.assertEqual(sales_items.count(), 1, 'Expected one sales item for this company, but got %s' % sales_items.count())
AssertionError: Expected one sales item for this company, but got 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.313s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I find this bit unnecessary.  I need to know the test name (method) that failed and the assert message. No need for traceback really..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kave/projects/my/my_app/tests.py", line 61, in test_get_sales_item_for_company
    self.assertEqual(sales_items.count(), 1, 'Expected one sales item for this company, but got %s' % sales_items.count())
```

Comment: Are you willing to go into the Django code (that is, change it for your installation)?

Comment: Ah I see. So there is no settings for this.  Hmm better not, since the Django code is bullet proof and I always could introduce bugs by doing that. Its not worth it I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monkey patching to the rescue. You can get rid of the traceback for failures without touching your Django installation by subclassing Django's TestCase as follows:

```
import types
from django.utils.unittest.result import failfast
from django.test import TestCase

@failfast
def addFailureSansTraceback(self, test, err):
    err_sans_tb = (err[0], err[1], None)
    self.failures.append((test, self._exc_info_to_string(err_sans_tb, test)))
    self._mirrorOutput = True

class NoTraceTestCase(TestCase):
    def run(self, result=None):
        result.addFailure = types.MethodType(addFailureSansTraceback, result)
        super(NoTraceTestCase, self).run(result)
```

Now just make your test cases subclasses of `NoTraceTestCase` instead of `TestCase` and you are good to go. No more tracebacks for failures. (Note exceptions will still print tracebacks. You could monkey-patch those away similarly if you wanted to.)

Here's how it works (with thanks to [Jason Pratt for the quick lesson on monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object)):

1. Django's test runner calls TestCase's `run` method for each test run. The `result` parameter is an instance of the `django.utils.unittest.result.TestResult` class, which handles showing test results to the user. Whenever a test fails, `run` makes the following call: `result.addFailure(self, sys.exc_info())`. That's where the traceback comes from -- as the third item in the tuple returned by `sys.exc_info()`.
2. Now, simply overriding `run` with a copy of the original code and tweaking it as needed would work. But the `run` method is a good 75 lines long, and all that needs to be changed is that one line, and in any case why miss out the chance for some fun with monkey-patching?
3. The `result.addFailure` assignment changes the `addFailure` method in the `result` object that is passed to NoTraceTestCase's `run` method to the newly defined `addFailureSansTraceback` function -- which is first transformed into a `result`-object compatible method with `types.MethodType`.
4. The `super` call invokes Django's existing TestCase `run`. Now, when the existing code runs, the call to `addFailure` will actually call the new version, i.e. `addFailureSansTraceback`.
5. `addFailureSansTraceback` does what the original version of `addFailure` does -- copying over two lines of code -- except adds a line that replaces the traceback with `None` (the assignment to `err_sans_tb` which is used instead of `err` in the next line). That's it.
6. Note the original `addFailure` has a `failfast` decorator, so that is imported and used. To be honest, I haven't looked at what it does!

Disclaimer: I haven't studied Django's test code thoroughly. This is just a quick patch to get it to work in the common case. Use at your own risk!

Comment: FYI anybody wondering: the `failfast` decorator simply checks for the `--failfast` switch, and stops (i.e. fails fast) if it is present.